# WAP power profile?

Tags: router, wireless

**Context**

The company I work for provides for its workers an ethernet and, for temporary visitors, a limited bandwidth/time wifi.

There is a new trend in France: Wifi and RF are the devil.

**Question**

First. Let's consider we set all our access points to 100% power profile. If there is no activity on the WIFI (let's say we have only ssid broadcast and keepalives). If you consider the amount of power sent in to the air through WIFI: Is that configuration quite equivalent to no wifi at all ?

Secondly. We do not have a good geographic cover so lowering power profiles would make things worst. Can something be done to automatically adapt the signal strength based on the client's signal strength ?

**Edit:**
As commented, what I called 'router' is indeed wifi access points.

Comment: What "routers" do you mean? Are they WAPs? If so, you should look at using a WLC. Also, a wireless site survey is a must. It will determine the proper WAP quantity, placement, power levels, channels, etc.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

If your access points have no clients associated with them, then they only send beacons. That’s a very low duty cycle.

To adjust the transmit power effectively, you need a survey, as @ronmaupin recommends.